# Why does some of my heroes have negative xp crystal costs?

Tags: marvel-puzzle-quest

I decided to fire up my Marvel Puzzle Quest over the holidays, after not having played it for a while. After the game updated (on my PC) and I got into the game, I noticed that some of my heroes now have negative XP crystal costs to level up. Why is that? Other of the heroes are ok. New heroes recruited do not have this issue either. So what is causing this issue?

Comment: Can you give me an example of who? And the approximate last time you played?

Comment: 2 star Thor Marvel Now. I hadn't played in about a year before first firing it up. His XP to raise a level is about double, since it always starts negative. For instance, at level 22, it started the cost to raise him at -218/248. So I have to spend 458 XP crystals to raise him to level 23. Most of my other heroes are ok. But every time I level up this 2 star Thor Now character, he starts in the negative numbers, not at 0 for XP crystals needed for next level.

Comment: According to http://marvelpuzzlequest.wikia.com/wiki/Thor_(Marvel_NOW!) and other research, this version of Thor was changed around the end of January 2014. This could have something to do with your issue.

Comment: The base levels of all non one-star characters got changed quite a while ago - could also have something to do with that

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find a root cause for you, but here's a post from the D3 Go! forums:

[Character has negative XP?](https://d3go.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=31955)

One of the moderators suggested this:

> Try playing a Prologue fight with your bugged character(s). Like
>   mentioned above, a little while ago, there was a change in ISO costs,
>   and a while before that there was a change that caused a similar issue
>   - in the latter case playing a game with the character fixed it. I'm not sure about here, but it's worth a shot.

But, the poster reported that, in this case, it didn't fix the issue. Another moderator suggested opening a support ticket with this link:

[Bug/Ticket Creation Procedure](https://d3publisher.helpshift.com/a/marvel-puzzle-quest/)